# How to handle Legacy code (Hydra code, complicated code), with a lot of customizations in PHP

Tags: php, magento, optimization, checkout

We have a Magento 1.4. We have OnePageCheckout extension installed. Our Checkout logic was customized a lot of times: there was implemented Tax customization, Next Day Delivery customization, Payment methods customization, Shipping methods customization, Detecting and getting City/State according entered Zip Code, etc. As a result - we have a very complicated logic, and if we fixing one issue, sometimes we are getting new instead.

So, my question is: what is the best approach to handle this logic?

I will be appreciate for your answers.
Thanks

Comment: You mean Spaghetti Code with a side order of GOTO statements? Study how Magento does it, break it all down into its component parts and rewrite it all into modules. On a DEV server so the issues don't kill the live site...

Comment: Yep, Spaghetti Code. Ok, thank you for your answer, i appreciate.